# Find the sum of all rows with same value.

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe which looks like this -

```
>df
words num 
his    92   
his    91   
there  91   
you    90   
who    90   
come   89   
you    70
```

Now, I want to aggregate the common words and sum their `num` column. So my final output would be like  -

```
words   num
his     183   
there   91   
you     160   
who     90   
come    89
```

How can I do this in R? I know it is something simple but not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[, sum(num), by=words]
   words  V1
1:   his 183
2: there  91
3:   you 160
4:   who  90
5:  come  89
```